# PHP Laravel Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Tags: php, laravel

Помогите разобраться ,сейчас создаю бд через Laravel и вроде бы все правильно сделала но выводит такая ошибка SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.

Это мой файл  .env где я прописываю название БД итд (если что работаю с xampp)  а это командная строка >
php artisan migrate- через которую я хочу создать БД

DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889

DB_DATABASE=larevel_blog

DB_USERNAME=root

DB_PASSWORD=root

Comment: Может быть у вас ошибка в ```larevel_blog```? И ```php artisan migrate``` не создает БД, она создает только таблицы

Comment: нет ,я правильно прописала названия БД

Comment: Откройте любой IDE для работы с БД (MySQLWorkbench, DataGrip), вбейте туда ваши данные для соединения и проверьте.